# Is there any API endpoint in Git hub to read wikis

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-api

Purpose is to get content from both public and private repositories. In addition to that looking for a scheduled syncing process to update the content in my endpoint when the git Hub wiki updates (As a further enhancement).

https://github.com/user/project.wiki.git tried this but it does not fit to my purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub wikis are git-backed and as far as I know there is no REST API alternative.

This was the original blog announcement:
https://github.blog/2010-08-12-making-github-more-open-git-backed-wikis/

So I think the git interface at `https://github.com/user/project.wiki.git`, as you mentioned, is the only option.